# Python module importing, IIS 10, FastCGI

Tags: python, flask, iis, fastcgi

I am running IIS version 10, I have configured FastCGI and have successfully run an Python Flask app. The thing I am having trouble with is importing another module.

In the C:\inetpub\wwwroot\flask\ folder I have the following files:

- test.py
- limits.py
- web.config

The web.config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<modules>
            <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
        </modules>
  <handlers>
   <add name="Python FastCGI"
     path="*"
     verb="*"
     modules="FastCgiModule"
     scriptProcessor="C:\Python\Python310\python.exe|C:\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py"
     resourceType="Unspecified"
     requireAccess="Script" />
  </handlers>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
</system.webServer>
<appSettings>
  <!-- Required settings -->
  <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="test.app" />
  <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\flask\" />
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

The test.py file looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, request
import limits


app = Flask(__name__)


class Middleware(object):
#class for URL sorting
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        if environ['PATH_INFO'].lower().replace('/flaskredirect','') == '/validate_mu':
            environ['PATH_INFO'] = environ['PATH_INFO'].lower().replace('/flaskredirect','')
            return self.app(environ, start_response)
        else:
            start_response('404', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
            return ["This url does not belong to the app.".encode()]


app.wsgi_app = Middleware(app.wsgi_app)

@app.route('/validate_mu', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def validate_mu():
    content_type = request.headers.get('Content-Type')
    if content_type == 'application/json':
        json_data = request.json
        #return limits.validate(json_data)
        return "JSON"
    else:
        return "Not JSON"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

If I comment out the line "import limits" everything works as expected. I get the response "JSON" or "Not JSON" and in case of an unexpected URL I get "This url does not belong to the app."

If I try to import limits.py I get:

```
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
```

I have tried adding the C:\inetpub\wwwroot\flask\ directory to FastCGI application environment variable PYTHONPATH. I have tried creating a new folder for modules and moving the limits.py to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\flask\modules where there is `__init__.py` file present and using "import modules.limits". That did not work.

Any suggestions?

Best Regards
SilverR

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/ FastCGI for Python is no longer recommended.

Comment: Do you get an error when running in a local development environment? Or will the error appear only after deploying to IIS?

Comment: Everything worked in IDE. The error only appeared after deploying to IIS. And the problem got solved by using HttpPlatformHandler instead of FastCGI, as recommended.